# Is it possible to send a get request to any website?

Tags: http, http-get

For example, if I went to website that sells products and searched for `'catfood'` and opened up a product while the developer tools in chrome are open so I can see the network requests that are made by browser.

I can see where the request went when I look at the network tab and I can also see what type of headers the server accepts.

So if we have these two things for example:

Where the request went:

```
www.website.com/products/5
```

What type the server accepts:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

If I would now create a HTTP request using `Angulars` `HttpClient` module like this:

```
    this._url = 'www.website.com/products/5';
    this._headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
});

this._http.get(this._url,this._headers).subscribe((value)=>console.log(value));
```

Why does this return an error?

In my case it is:

```
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
```

Comment: The answer to the question in the title (can a request be sent to any website) is a simple "yes"; that's how the web works. The question at the end about a particular piece of AngularJS code is a completely different question, and one which would need more context (preferably a [mcve]) to answer.

Comment: Yes the question was a bit poorly worded, what I wanted to ask if there's a way that the server knows that the request is coming from code rather than browser?

Comment: In that case the answer is strictly "no", but you may need to work harder to *look like* the browser. Or, you might just have created your request wrong, which I rather suspect given the error message you got back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "too broad", because I think you'll get better answers if you can focus your question on either some theoretical aspect of how HTTP requests work (after seeing if you can find a basic introduction to the topic first) or the particular request you were trying to make (including an [mcve], and appropriate tags in the question so the right people will see it).